# the disk is offline because of critical write failures

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I have this error in computer management, yet according to VMs (name of Virtual Disk) properties the volume is healthy. As a result the volume is offline and I can not mount it nor start the lab VMs on this host.

This is some hardware I inherited to run some tests on, It's been 100% reliable until this but it's a good desktop desktop, nothing server grade - We added 2x mSATA PCI-E card by Vantec (Marvell chipset, drivers build into Windows I believe but someone else could have installed some drivers). I assume the controller is related to why it failed. The box was a clean Win 2012 R2 + installing graphics card driver and maybe os boot raid controller driver (someone else installed Windows so I have a few unknowns).

During some heavy usage, moving some VMs to this new tiered storage, the server blue screened and now the volume can't be brought online (yet Hyper-V finished moving the boot volume of a host and changed location of file).

Some basic details:

The only visible error:
[image]

> PS C:\temp> Test-SpacesConfiguration -StoragePoolFriendlyName HostPool

```
This Storage Pool, the Storage Spaces created from this pool, and the
Physial Disks in the Storage Pool are all currently healthy. True
```

> PS C:\temp> Get-SpacesPoolPhysicalDiskHWCounter HostPool

```
PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk1
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_Samsung&Prod_SSD_850_EVO_mSAT\5&177c7049&0&020000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 0
PowerOnHours              : 2
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 13
WriteLatencyMax           : 11

PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk5
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_WDC&Prod_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1\4&329b9fed&0&030000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 44
PowerOnHours              : 607
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 626
WriteLatencyMax           : 29

PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk0
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_Samsung&Prod_SSD_850_EVO_mSAT\5&177c7049&0&000000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 0
PowerOnHours              : 2
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 6
WriteLatencyMax           : 9

PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk4
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_WDC&Prod_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1\4&329b9fed&0&020000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 46
PowerOnHours              : 607
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 613
WriteLatencyMax           : 19

PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk7
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_WDC&Prod_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1\4&329b9fed&0&050000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 48
PowerOnHours              : 606
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 55
WriteLatencyMax           : 605

PhysicalDiskFriendlyName  : PhysicalDisk6
PhysicalDiskUniqueID      : SCSI\Disk&Ven_WDC&Prod_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1\4&329b9fed&0&040000:WIN-PO59ODAIC8U
CurrentTemperatureCelsius : 46
PowerOnHours              : 607
ReadErrorsTotal           : 0
WriteErrorsTotal          :
ReadLatencyMax            : 626
WriteLatencyMax           : 22
```

I could keep dumping data like event logs but since there's zero posts about this problem online I don't expect many people have answers for me.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm experiencing the same issue.  I'll update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since the disk stats you've posted don't indicate any errors in the read/write to each physical disk (....you did still test them with the manufacturers tool, eg long read test?), and the system is a relatively clean/fresh install state, then, suspect the sata card firmware(update it?), chipset driver, lastly other hardware.

Can you swing the physical drives from the sata card to the onboards ports located on the mainboard (if spares exist), and remove the addon card, and see if it hangs again under heavy load situations?

If not, try another card with a different chipset.

Are you using a parity type space?  If so  mprime, and memtest the system and see if those cause a BSOD. Parity space would need additional CPU cycles for the redundancy calculations.

I've had similar issues in the past with flaky hardware dropping drives that were OK (it was the damn back plane in the system).

JC

Comment: Everything you said is absolutely correct - But my bigger point is there's no error details that say why this won't come online nor any clear path to bringing it online.  As to hardware - Most of the things are tested, a few aren't after the most - As I said, it's not really server grade so we don't expect perfect - But we *DO* expect the software to have a path to recovery in the software - Not via support or discussions, given this is a build in Windows feature - There is no chkdsk / fsck / etc.